# insert error system.format.exception vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert

At my software, a error just surfaced, it was working, but I get the following error when running the insert command.
I'm using VB.NET with MySQL.

Error message:

```
{System.FormatException: Cadeia de caracteres de entrada com formato incorrecto.
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseUInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   em System.String.System.IConvertible.ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   em MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBit.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object value, Int32 length)
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute()
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   em BARCOSEGUR.uccbarcosegurDataSetTableAdapters.suspeitaTableAdapter.Insert(String p1, Nullable`1 p2, String p3, Object p4, Object p5, Object p6, Object p7) em C:\Users\g1960931\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BARCOSEGUR\BARCOSEGUR\uccbarcosegurDataSet.Designer.vb:line 25533
   em BARCOSEGUR.Vigilância.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em C:\Users\g1960931\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BARCOSEGUR\BARCOSEGUR\Vigilância.vb:line 104}
```

When I run the insert query directly from the data designer, it works fine, so I think the problem is not at insert query

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO suspeita (idembarcacao, suspeita_desde, colocada_por, opcao1, opcao2, opcao3, opcao4) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7)
```

If run from dataset it inserts without a problem.

This is my code:

```
Dim dt As Date
dt = System.DateTime.Today
dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd")
Me.SuspeitaTableAdapter.Insert(tst, dt, util, op1, op2, op3, op4) 
Me.SuspeitaTableAdapter.Update(Me.UccbarcosegurDataSet.suspeita)
```

**Variable Types**

```
 1. tst = string
 2. dt = date
 3. util = string
 4. op1,op2,op3 = integer
 5. op4 = string
```

**Table is created as follows**

```
 1. idembarcacao = varchar(11)
 2. suspeita_desde = date
 3. colocada_por = varchar(45)
 4. opcao1 = int(11)
 5. opcao2 = int(11)
 6. opcao3 = int(11)
 7. opcao4 = varchar(85)
```

Can someone please help me. I'm lost.

Comment: If your column is a `date` then don't turn it into a string. Dates only have formats when presented to humans - in the database they have no format they are binary so use a `DateTime` command parameter.

Comment: @Crowcoder The code fortuitously doesn't use the return value of the function.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good catch.

Comment: You could put a [debugger breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017) at the line `Me.SuspeitaTableAdapter.Insert(tst, dt, util, op1, op2, op3, op4)` and check that all those variables have the values you expect.

Comment: Already inserted the breakpoint, and yes the values are as expected. The only thing that suspect is the problem is that when you write the line, all the variables are as suposed (string, date.....) except the op1 op2 and op3 that are as object, not integer. Could this be the problem

Comment: Andrew Norton, i've followed your advice, and commented the line that was turnng the date into a string, but the error still  the same

Comment: @user3223158 I suggest that you use [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). It may point out problems that lead to those variables being objects instead of integers. (The line you commented out wasn't actually changing anything.)

Comment: hi andrew and thank's for you help in advance. I've turned Option Strict ON, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ago, I had the same problem. In my case, the solution was, to add `Convert Zero Datetime=True` to the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I thanks to all of you for your help. Solved the problem, with a simple action, deleted the insert query at the dataset and recreated the same. The problem that i mencioned above with the object, disapeared and everything is working like a charm. THANK YOU ALL, you're all the best.